# What is the most commonly used sign on the Name engraved ring?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I'm having a bit of trouble connecting in Coop so I started using the name engraved ring to widen the scope a bit, but I don't know which sign to use. There are so many! Does anyone know which God is the most commonly used?

Comment: Blue Sentinels & Sun bros.

Comment: Those aren't gods, they are covenants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regards to which group is most popular, I can honestly not tell you, nor do I know how you would find out as the only way you could is statistics unavailable to the average player or personal testing, but even then the popularity of each one may vary daily.

I can however provide you with some advice that may help with your problem, similar to my answer to your second question, the ring's purpose is to block connections to everyone but the people in the same group. This means that if it is general co op you are after, the ring is not really the way to go unless you are wanting to play with friends that you can tell what group to go in.

Also what is your issue with connectivity? finding signs or actually connecting when you use them? If it is the latter your problem may be completely different. I haven't played Dark Souls 2 for a little while but I assume it is still very popular, so there should in theory be no problem with finding signs.

Hope this helps.